# How to set a friendly url for a hidden page in WebSphere Portal 7

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal, websphere-7

We need to create a couple of pages for our WebSphere Portal 7 installation which a user can access without having to log in to the portal. We'd also like these pages to have friendly URLs (e.g. http://portal/wps/somePage). We'd like the page to be "hidden" so that it does not show up in the titlebar (next to "Home", "Search Center", etc.).

I can create a page with a friendly URL, however if I create such a page under the "Hidden Pages" section the friendly page doesn't appear to work. So how can I create a page which is both hidden and accessible via a friendly URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end we create the page as you would for any other page (e.g. in the content root) and set the friendly URL and then had to export the page using XMLAccess. We then edited the XML to add the "com.ibm.portal.Hidden" page metadata attribute, deleted the page from the Portal, and re-imported the updated page using XMLAccess.

In this way we were able to create a hidden self-registration page with a URL similar to the following:

http://portal.domain.com/wps/portal/selfregistration

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the page below the level of the default page in the (virtual) portal. If you look closely at the Manage Pages you will notice that it is possible.

Also, you could not add friendly URL for your hidden page and use the front-end IHS/Apache to redirect from your selected friendly URL to the hidden page (with a horrible mess of URL, but the users would not see it on the first page load.) Mod_rewrite can easily accomplish that for you.

Comment: I don't understand how your answer relates to my question, sorry. But I already found the answer I was looking for elsewhere (see my answer below). Thanks anyway!

Comment: @GaZ You managed to do the exactly same with 10 times more work :)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? mod_rewrite is not an option for us.

Answer (score 0):

The friendly URL you refer is the friendly name or path. If you want to address a page using this method you have to get all elements on the path to this page a friendly URL as well.
In your case the Hidden Pages do not have a name set to the system does only check for a path element with the name somePage below the root node. 
You could have added a friendly URL to the Hidden Page label as well, so your URL would have been
https://portal/wps/[hiddenpagepath]/somePage)
Using this you can build a URL to every element within your Page hierarchy